# Angular 5 HTTP Interceptors error message

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I'm having a problem with my Angular 5: HTTP Interceptors.  I'm new here so please be patient as I learn how all of this works. This is my error message:

```
 compiler.js:19514 Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
 Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS 
 ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

and this is my interceptor code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from'@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../_services/authentication.service';



 @Injectable()
 export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < 
 HttpEvent < any >> {

    this.authService.id_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    // Retrieving the JWT string from Local Storage directly

    if (this.authService.id_token) { // We are checking if the JWT is present

        const cloned = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken(this.authService.username, this.authService.password))

        });
        return next.handle(cloned); // If the JWT is not present, then the request goes through to the server unmodified

    } else {

        return next.handle(req); // If the JWT is present, then we will clone the HTTP headers, and add an extra Authorization header, which will contain the JWT
    }
   }
}
```

I'm importing the Authentication Service but don't know what else to do, I've tried to inject it and it does not work. Please help.

```
          @NgModule({
         declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         NavbarComponent,
         hatitPageComponent,
         hatitLitePageComponent,
         hatitbodyComponent,
         hatitLitebodyComponent,
         MeterqueryComponent,
         MeterlinesideComponent,
         MeterloadsideComponent,
         MeterstatusComponent,
         CommstatusComponent,
         MeterlistComponent,
         MessagecenterComponent,
         FooterComponent,
         WhatsnewComponent,
         MeterresultsComponent,
         DefaultareaComponent,
         InstructionsComponent,
         AuthComponent,
         HomeComponent,
        ],
        imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         FormsModule,
         RoutingModule,
         HttpClientModule,
         BrowserAnimationsModule,
         MatProgressSpinnerModule,
             ],
       providers: [
          ClockService,
          MessageCenterService,
          MeterService,
          DaqService,
          AuthenticationService,
          AuthGuard,
          hatitGuard,
          hatitLiteGuard,
          VersionService,
          {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS , useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true}
          ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
                })
        export class AppModule {
     }


import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdGroup } from '../_models/adgroup.model';
import { adGroupsEnum } from '../_enums/adgroups.enum';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthenticationService {

    username: any;
    password: any;
    loggedInUsername: string;
    loggedInUserADGroups: string[] = [];
    loggedInUserADGroupModels: AdGroup[] = [];
    // tokenExpirationTimer: any;

    isAuthenticated = false;
    isAuthenticatedSubject: BehaviorSubject < boolean > = new BehaviorSubject(false);

           authApiEndpoint = '';

           hatitCall = '';
           // userAuthURL = '';

           id_token = null;
           refresh_token = null;
           access_token = null;
           // tokenRefreshInterval: any;

           consumer_key_empim = '';
           consumer_secret_empim = '';

           constructor(private http: HttpClient,
          private router: Router) {
             this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
           }

           ADDGroupMapper(adGroup: string) {
             const adGroupEnumElem = adGroupsEnum[adGroup];
             return new AdGroup(
               adGroupEnumElem['adGroupName'],
               adGroupEnumElem['adGroupEnv'],
               adGroupEnumElem['adGroupApp']
             );
           }

           getUserADDGroups(userName) {
             this.loggedInUserADGroups = [];
             this.loggedInUserADGroupModels = [];
             const url = this.getAuthDSEndPoint();
             const params = new HttpParams()
               .set('lanId', userName)
               .set('domain', this.getUserDomain());
             console.log(url);
             return this.http.get(url, {
               params: params,
               responseType: 'text'
             });
           }


            getToken(username, password): Observable < any > {
                const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.consumer_key_emp + ':' + this.consumer_secret_empim)
                });
                if (username && password) {

                let formData = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password)
                    + '&scope=openid msso&grant_type=password';

                return this.http.post(this.getAuthEndPoint(), formData, {
                    headers: headers,
                });
                }
                return null;
            }


                getBackEndRefreshToken() {
                    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.consumer_key_emp + ':' + this.consumer_secret_empim)
                    });
                    const formData = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=';
                    return this.http.post(this.getAuthEndPoint(), formData)
                    .map(response => response)
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.clearSession();
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    }).subscribe(response => {

                        this.setAccessToken(this.access_tokenim);
                        this.setRefreshToken(this.refresh_tokenim);

                        localStorage.setItem('access_token', this.access_tokenim);
                        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', this.refresh_tokenim);
                    });
                }

                loginUser(username, password, id_token): Observable<any> {
                    this.id_token = id_token;
                    const headers = new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.consumer_key_emp + ':' + this.consumer_secret_empim)
                    });
                    const header = new Headers({ headers: headers });
                    this.getBackEndRefreshToken();
                    if (username && password) {
                    const formData = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password)
                        + '&scope=openid msso&grant_type=password';

                    return this.http.post(this.hatitCall, formData).map(res => res);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                // loginUser(token):  Observable<any> {
                //   this.id_token = token;
                //   const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                //     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                //     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.consumer_key_emp + ':' + this.consumer_secret_empim)
                //     });
                //     const options  = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                //   const formData = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(this.username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(this.password)
                //     + '&scope=openid msso&grant_type=password';
                //       return this.http.post(this.hatitCall, formData, options).map(res => res);
                // }

                logOut(): void {
                    this.clearSession();
                }

                isUserAuthenticated(): boolean {
                    return this.isAuthenticated;
                }

                hashatitAppAccess() {
                    const appLookUp = 'hatit';
                    // console.log('Checking for hatit Access');
                    if (this.loggedInUserADGroupModels.length > 0) {
                    for (const adg of this.loggedInUserADGroupModels) {
                        if (adg.adGroupApp === appLookUp) {
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                hashatitLiteAppAccess() {
                    const appLookUp = 'hatitLite';
                    // console.log('Checking for hatitLite Access');
                    if (this.loggedInUserADGroupModels.length > 0) {
                    for (const adg of this.loggedInUserADGroupModels) {
                        if (adg.adGroupApp === appLookUp) {
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                clearSession() {
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                }

                getRefreshToken() {
                    return sessionStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
                }

                setAccessToken(token) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
                }
                setRefreshToken(token) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('refresh_token', token);
                }
                getUserDomain() {
                    return 'NAM';
                }

                getAuthEndPoint() {
                    return this.authApiEndpoint + this.hatitCall;
                }

                getAuthDSEndPoint() {
                    return this.authApiEndpoint + this.hatitCall;
                }
                getAccessToken() {
                    return sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
                }
                }
```

Comment: can you include your module and authentication service code?

Comment: the error is in your NgModule, please paste related code

Comment: okay I did what you asked @haifzhan

Comment: please post code for authservice too, as i believe you have injected HttpClient in your auth service.

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh i did it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpInterceptor->Service->HttpClient Cyclic Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213352/httpinterceptor-service-httpclient-cyclic-dependency)

Comment: Try updating to angular 5.2.3, they fixed some cyclic dependency issues in that release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how me and a colleague fixed it:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from 
'@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../_services/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
private authService: AuthenticationService;

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {
   }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 if (req.url.includes('token')) {
return next.handle(req);
}

this.authService = this.inj.get(AuthenticationService);

 const cloned = req.clone({
headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
this.authService.getAccessToken())
});

 return next.handle(cloned); // If the JWT is not present, then the 
 request goes through to the server unmodified
}

}
```

Basically had to Inject this way the authentication service, as opposed to how I had it before.

Comment: so, basically now you are creating new instance of authentication service for all http request. It will have performance impact and it's just an workaround, not a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have services depending on each others ,try this to inject AuthenticationService manually in your interceptor and break the circular dependency

```
 constructor(injector: Injector) {
   this.authService= injector.get(AuthenticationService)
}
```

or you inject it inside your intercept function
    constructor(injector: Injector) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < 
 HttpEvent < any >> {

```
const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the reason you are getting is because of below code

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
             this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
    }
}
```

Here **HttpClient** and **Router** service is causing the issue for you. So to solve your problem, you need split your service into smaller code and separate their concerns. Below are the steps you should follow to resolve the issue

1. Keep the http calling services out of authentication service
2. share the token and user information using another singleton service i.e. AuthService which does not have any dependency.
3. Trigger events from http calling service rather than AuthService
4. Inject AuthService into http calling service & Interceptor to share data

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from '../account.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AccountService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Get the auth token from the service.
   const authToken = this.authToken.getToken();

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
    if (authToken) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + authToken ?? "")
      });// send cloned request with header to the next handler.
      return next.handle(authReq);
    }
    return next.handle(req);

  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).