# Angular 6 enters infinite loop of cyclic dependency when I inject a service that uses HttpClient inside my HttpInterceptor class

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-http-interceptors, cyclic-dependency

I have found this issue many times in different Angular versions but multiple sources say it is already fixed, for example, another similar question on Stackoverflow is having [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683766/7588447) which says that it was solved in Angular 5.2 , [some other issues on Github are saying it solved in 6.0.2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224#issuecomment-316957213) , I am using Angular 6.0.3 but still I get that issue, whenever I try injecting a service that uses HttpClient inside my HttpInterceptor class (that should add a jwt token to the requests if the jwt was received in that service)

I don't get a warning or error that I have cyclic dependency, put I can see in the browser console thousands of requests that the Interceptor is calling the service & vice-versa.

***What is the proper way to handle this issue?*** (preferably without storing jwt in localstorage)

(i.e using the interceptor & getting the jwt from the service)

My service:

```
 ....
 // only showing parts that matter, HttpClient is injected here
 // to be used in calling the API services

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute,
 public translate: TranslateService, private router: Router,
 public snackBar: MatSnackBar, private notification: NotificationService) {

//
```

My HttpInterceptor:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data/data.service';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const dataService = this.injector.get(DataService);

  console.log('hey there, we are here INTERCEPTOR');
  if (dataService.jwt) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${dataService.jwt}`
          }
        });
      }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

ng version

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.0.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.1.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.15
@angular/material                 6.3.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around it by instantiating HttpClient myself inside the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(httpBackend: HttpBackend) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(httpBackend);    
  }
}
```

This broke the infinite loop issue in my case (using Angular@6.1.10).