# HttpInterceptor->Custom Service->Module circular dependency

Tags: angular

In my angular 10 app my core module contains the following 2 services :

1.HttpResponseInterceptor - intercepts the http response and if its status is 401 redirect to some login page.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (!!error.status && error.status === 401) {
        window.location.href = this.configService.getLoginPage();
        return NEVER;
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
```

2.ConfigService - responsible for loading config file from the filesystem with some environment data

```
@Injectable({providedIn: CoreModule})
export class ConfigService{
  private readonly CONFIG_URL = 'assets/cfg.json';
  public configuration: Configuration;
  public wasEnvLoaded = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.loadConfigurations();
  }

  public loadConfigurations(): any {
    if (!this.configuration) {
      this.httpClient.get<Configuration>(this.CONFIG_URL).subscribe((config: Configuration) => {
          this.configuration = config;
          this.wasEnvLoaded = true;
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and my core module :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [ {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpResponseInterceptor, multi : true}],
  declarations: []
})

export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('CoreModule is already loaded. Import only in AppModule');
    }
  }
}
```

I implemented the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213352/httpinterceptor-service-httpclient-cyclic-dependency) and everything works fine. However, I'm still getting circular dependency warning between the services and the core module. Can anyone explain why ?

```
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private loginPage: string;
  private configurationLoaderService: ConfigurationLoaderService;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.configurationLoaderService = this.injector.get(ConfigurationLoaderService);
      this.loginPage = this.configurationLoaderService.configuration.cognitoLoginURL;
    });
  } 

intercept(...){
```

Error:

> circual error : ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ConfigService

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `{providedIn: CoreModule}` is pretty useless if it's only injected in your root module. Just use `{ providedIn: 'root' }`, that's much better. That will fix your circulair dependency. Another way would be to add the `ConfigService` to your providers array of your module, and remove the `providedIn` object from the service</strike>

Your main issue is that the `ConfigService` uses the `HttpClient`, but the `ConfigService` is also used in the `HttpResponseInterceptor`, which is called from the `HttpClient`. So there is your circular dependency. HttpClient needs ConfigService and the other way around.

You should split the functionality into two separate classes. Not knowing your entire code, I can give you this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigDataService {
  private config?: Configuration; 
 
  getLoginPage(): string {
    return this.config?.loginPage;
  }

  setConfiguration(config: Configuration): {
    this.config = config;
  } 
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService{
  private readonly CONFIG_URL = 'assets/cfg.json';
  public wasEnvLoaded = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private cd: ConfigDataService) {
    this.loadConfigurations();
  }

  public loadConfigurations(): any {
    if (!this.configuration) {
      this.httpClient.get<Configuration>(this.CONFIG_URL).subscribe((config: Configuration) => {
          this.cd.setConfiguration(config)
          this.wasEnvLoaded = true;
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cd: ConfigDataService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (!!error.status && error.status === 401) {
        window.location.href = this.cd.getLoginPage();
        return NEVER;
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
```

Comment: CoreModule isnt my root module.

Comment: You suggest to replace the {providedIn: CoreModule} in my configService to { providedIn: 'root' } although its not provided in root. Can you explain why? I'm not following

Comment: I tried to add the ConfigService to the providers array in my CoreModule + injecting the configService in the constructor of the interceptor but I still get circual error : ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ConfigService

Comment: @JeyJ From what I understand, the `CoreModule` is only imported once, and is part of your root/core modules/services. By setting `providedIn: 'root'`, you are telling angular that this particular class should only be instantiated once and will thus act as a singleton, which I think is the behavior you want. The possibility of setting the providedIn to a certain module is mainly used by lib makers, as far as I can remember

Comment: I changed the providedIn to 'root' in the ConfigService. It didnt help.. Not sure if its related, but my app component (the root module) injects in its constructor the ConfigService : export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService) {
  }

Comment: @JeyJ I was a bit too quick with my answer, I think I see what is wrong, but it's difficult to explain. I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm not getting the circular dependency error anymore and everything is loaded sucessfully, but I'm still getting a warning in webstarm, why is that ?  WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\core\core.module.ts -> src\app\core\services\http-response-interceptor.ts -> src\app\core\core.module.ts