# NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

Tags: angular, electron

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.1
Node: 14.8.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.1
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.1
@angular/cli                    11.0.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.1
@schematics/update              0.1100.1
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
```

when i use translateService with httpInterceptor, i got this error:

> NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

It works well if i don't use translateService,can anyone help me solve this problem,here is the codes

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from './services';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AppConfig } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private electronService: ElectronService,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    console.log('AppConfig', AppConfig);
  }
}
```

core.module.ts

```
import {InjectionToken, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../app-routing.module';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppStoreModule} from '../store/app-store.module';
import {ViewsModule} from '../views/views.module';
import {httpInterceptorProvides} from '../services/http-interceptor';
import {API_BASE_URL} from '../services/service.module';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppStoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ViewsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      useValue: 'https://demo.xx.com'
    },
    httpInterceptorProvides,
  ],
  exports: [AppRoutingModule, SharedModule]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

httpinterceptor.ts

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthService} from '../auth.service';
import {API_BASE_URL} from '../service.module';

@Injectable()
export class CommonInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  skipUrl: string[];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, @Inject(API_BASE_URL) private uri: string) {
    this.skipUrl = ['/oauth/token', 'assets/i18n'];
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const req = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Accept': 'dddd'
      },
      url: this.uri + request.url
    });
    // return next.handle(req);

    if (this.isSkipAuth(req.url)) {
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      return this.auth.getToken()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((access_token) => {
            const reqA = req.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
              }
            });
            return next.handle(reqA);
          })
        );
    }
  }

  isSkipAuth(url: string): boolean {
    let isMatch = false;
    this.skipUrl.forEach((reg_url: string) => {
      if (!isMatch) {
        if (url.search(reg_url) >= 0) {
          isMatch = true;
        }
      }
    });
    return isMatch;
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {ElectronService} from './electron/electron.service';
import {map, pluck, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ResponseType} from './data-types/common.type';

export interface TokenModel {
  access_token: string; // access_token
  expires: number; // 
  expires_in: number; // 
}



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  elStoreIns: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private elService: ElectronService) {
    this.elStoreIns = this.elService.elStore;
  }

  getToken(): Observable<string> {
    const now = Date.now();
    const tokenStore: TokenModel = this.elStoreIns.get('token');
    if (tokenStore instanceof Object) {
      if ((now - tokenStore.expires) <= 7100 * 1000) {
        return of(tokenStore.access_token);
      }
    }
    return this.requestToken();
  }

  requestToken(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<ResponseType>('/oauth/token', {
      client_ids: 1,
      client_secrets: 'ddd',
      grant_types: 'dddd'
    }).pipe(
      pluck('data'),
      tap((data: any) => {
        const tokenData: TokenModel = {
          access_token: data.access_token,
          expires_in: data.expires_in,
          expires: Date.now()
        };
        this.saveToken(tokenData);
      }),
      map(data => data.access_token)
    );
  }

  saveToken(tokenStore: TokenModel): void {
    this.elStoreIns.set('token', tokenStore);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have the same error without using the interceptors. i think the error has to do with the constructor and the circular dependency rather than the interceptors.

Comment: What are the dependencies of your `ElectronService`? Might be the problem is in there. You could try temporarily removing one dependency at the time and then you'll quickly isolate the issue. The error messages for circular dependencies are not always so descriptive...

Answer (score 9):

At first, angular will raise a "NG0200: Circular dependency" error as **soon as an error is thrown in a service constructor**. Even if this is not related to any dependency injection.

Now regarding interceptors, in short you cannot use a service within your interceptor itself using `HttpClient`because the `HttpClient` has a dependency on the interceptor. A workaround is to provide a brand new instance of `HttpClient` free of any inteceptors.

Answer (score 1):

run this command and you will see in which files circular dependencies located.

> npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./

Then fix imports.

Answer (score -2):

I am not 100% sure if its a valid and clean solution, but you could try to instanciate the "HttpClient" on your own in "auth.service.ts". Remove the HttpClient from your constructor, and try the following approach:

```
private http: HttpClient;

constructor(httpBackend: HttpBackend) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
}
```

Comment: Similar issue and possible solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213352/httpinterceptor-service-httpclient-cyclic-dependency